# Topological Entropy of $T$ on subset $Y\subset X$

Tags: entropy

Let $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and on it the following dynamics described by $T\colon X\to X$ as follows: A 1 becomes a 2, a 2 becomes a 0 and a 0 becomes a 1 if at least one of its two neighbors is 1.

Moreover, consider
$$
Y=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}T^n(X).
$$

Show that for the Topological Entropy of $T$ it is
$$
h(X,T)=h(Y,T).
$$

**Edit**

"$\leqslant$":
Because $Y\subset X$ is closed and $T(Y)=Y$, it is $h(Y,T)\leqslant h(X,T)$.

"$\geqslant$": How to show this?

Edit: Already found an answer by myself.

Comment: Please choose a title that gives some idea of what your question is about.

Comment: Ok, I changed the title.

Comment: Thank you! $\phantom{xxxxxxx}$

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own post.

Comment: ok. sorry. thought it can be deleted because i do not need an answer anymore since i found an answer by myself